# Lerping between to transforms progresses much faster than the lerp value intends

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, lerp

I want to make a object (fuse) fly towards another object (fuse box) and also adapt its transform.rotation values gradually. (I use `transform.position/rotation = Vector3/Quarteronin.Lerp(initial.position/rotation, fuseBox.position/rotation, progressTimer`))

These are the variables, declared outside the shown code:

```cs
private Transform closestFuseBoxTransform = null;
private Transform initialFuseTransform = null;
private float fuseSnappingProgress = -1f;
private float fuseSnapingAnimationTime = 100f;
private float fuseSnappingBezierStrength = 1f;
```

This is my code so far: (placed inside `Update()`)

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // Get initial and destination Transforms
    closestFuseBoxTransform = GetClosestObject(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("FuseDst"););
    initialFuseTransform = transform;

    //if-block gets "turned on"
    fuseSnappingProgress = 0f;
    Debug.Log(transform.rotation.eulerAngles);
}

if (fuseSnappingProgress >= 0f)
{
    // Increment real time timer
    fuseSnappingProgress += Time.deltaTime / fuseSnapingAnimationTime;

    // Makes transition fancy, works because x^y (y > 0) returns for 0 < x < 1 always 0 < y < 1
    float fuseSnappingProgressBezier = Mathf.Pow(fuseSnappingProgress, fuseSnappingBezierStrength);
    Debug.Log(fuseSnappingProgressBezier);

    // Set the transform values using initial and desired position and just calculated 'fuseSnappingProgressBezier'
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialFuseTransform.position, closestFuseBoxTransform.position,
                                      fuseSnappingProgressBezier);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialFuseTransform.rotation, closestFuseBoxTransform.rotation,
                                      fuseSnappingProgressBezier);

    // When the animation reaches 100%...
    if (fuseSnappingProgress >= 1f)
    {
        // Adjust for potential lag, that caused Time.deltaTime to be huge and make the timer jump past 1
        transform.position = closestFuseBoxTransform.position;
        transform.rotation = closestFuseBoxTransform.rotation;

        //if-block gets "turned off"
        fuseSnappingProgress = -1f;
        Debug.Log("Fuse snapped into cosest Fuse Box");
    }
}
```

This it what happens in-game: (The animation lasts 100 seconds (as intended) but the fuse already moved to the intended position (gets *Infinity* closer, but I cant spot the exponentials fot that) after a few seconds)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `initialFuseTransform` is a Transform which means it is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) which means that when you modify your object's transform, it is modifying the `initialFuseTransform` aswell. So instead of doing that, have 2 value types like `Vector3 initialPosition` and `Quaternion initialRotation` and handle your lerping based on these.

For more detail check out microsoft documentation for [value vs reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types).

Comment: solved by creating two separate variables for initialPosition and initialRotation and setting them to `new Vector3/Quaternion(transform.pos/rot.x, ... y ... z, transform.rot.w)`
There must be a better way but it works fine like this

Comment: @Cyklon3000 In what way do you think this could be made better? As it stands, this is the standard way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.